# NullPointerException while passing strings from an activity to a service

Tags: java, android

I am passing two strings from NewsFeed.java to CheckService.java

In NewsFeed.java,I am passing string through a bundle like this:

```
                        basket.putString("KEY1", id[i]);
                        basket.putString("KEY2", message[i]);
                        basket.putString("KEY3", timeFormat[i]);
                        passNotiData = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                CheckService.class);
                        passNotiData.putExtras(basket);            

                       getActivity().startService(passNotiData);
```

NewsFeed.java is a Fragment. This code is in a `doInBackground` method of an `AsynkTask`.
And in CheckService.java:

```
    Bundle gotBasket =intent.getExtras();
    oldId=gotBasket.getString("KEY1");
    oldTime=gotBasket.getString("KEY3");
```

I am getting error at `oldId=gotBasket.getString("KEY1");` as `NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION`. I have initialized `oldId` as `String oldId= new String();`

LOGCAT:

```
  03-23 02:04:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(16212): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[CheckService]
03-23 02:04:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(16212): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 02:04:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(16212):    at com.appquest.awaaziitkgp.notification.CheckService.doWakefulWork(CheckService.java:70)
03-23 02:04:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(16212):    at com.appquest.awaaziitkgp.notification.WakefulIntentService.onHandleIntent(WakefulIntentService.java:39)
03-23 02:04:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(16212):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
03-23 02:04:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(16212):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 02:04:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(16212):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 02:04:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(16212):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

BootBroadcast.java

```
    package com.appquest.awaaziitkgp.notification;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class BootBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int PERIOD = 60000; // 1 minutes

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
        // context.startService(myIntent);

        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000, PERIOD, pi);
    }

}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
    package com.appquest.awaaziitkgp.notification;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WakefulIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);

        context.startService(new Intent(context, CheckService.class));
    }

}
```

WakefulIntentService.java

```
package com.appquest.awaaziitkgp.notification;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;

abstract public class WakefulIntentService extends IntentService {

    abstract void doWakefulWork(Intent intent);

    public static final String LOCK_NAME_STATIC = "com.appquest.ServiceHandler.Static";
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock lockStatic = null;

    public static void acquireStaticLock(Context context) {
        getLock(context).acquire();
    }

    synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
        if (lockStatic == null) {
            PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

            lockStatic = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    LOCK_NAME_STATIC);
            lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
        }

        return (lockStatic);
    }

    public WakefulIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            doWakefulWork(intent);
        } finally {
            if (getLock(this).isHeld())
                getLock(this).release();

        }
    }

}
```

CheckService.java

```
package com.appquest.awaaziitkgp.notification;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.appquest.awaaziitkgp.ItemBean;
import com.appquest.awaaziitkgp.NewsFeed;
import com.appquest.awaaziitkgp.ServiceHandler;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CheckService extends WakefulIntentService {
    ItemBean item;
    NewsFeed news;
    JSONArray contacts;
    String newMessage, newTime, newId;
    // Notification ID to allow for future updates
    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    String oldId = new String();
    String oldTime = new String();
    public int onoff = 1;
    static int count = 0;
    // Notification Count
    private int mNotificationCount;

    // Notification Text Elements
    private final String tickerText = "This is a Really, Really, Super Long Notification Message!";
    private final String contentTitle = "Notification";
    private final String contentText = "You've Been Notified!";

    // Notification Action Elements
    private Intent mNotificationIntent;
    private PendingIntent mContentIntent;

    // Sound & Vibrations
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    long[] mVibratePattern = { 0, 200, 200, 200 };

    public CheckService() {
        super("CheckService");

    }

    // }

    @Override
    void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
        File log = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "AlarmLog.txt");
        if (onoff == 1) {

            Bundle gotBasket = intent.getExtras();
            oldId = gotBasket.getString("KEY1");
            oldTime = gotBasket.getString("KEY3");

            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh
                    .makeServiceCall(
                            "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/awaaziitkgp/feed?access_token=CAAK43Qt9dQUBAF0ZC3LYE828xyaaQgTccYYpWBmO7sqcsll4S3lhnVdBH0JrV30qPjjLWPwy0lPR0ZAt8Tsl5se0OGWWQejybyEWZCmPXJdjBhorBNWAudWXEZAuVaQnrpMkmcZAGsGO31aIHZA8SttfEkEi4rntmIweZBluWJ2ZAHi40tqiiXZCpKxE67L9qCrvlZBPGvXIdPvOErJZBbKYsZCp",
                            ServiceHandler.GET);

            mNotificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    NotificationSubActivity.class);
            mContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                    0, mNotificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(0);
                    newId = c.getString("id");
                    newTime = c.getString("created_time");
                    newMessage = c.getString("message");

                    if (oldId.equals(newId) == false) {
                        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
                                getApplicationContext())
                                .setTicker(newMessage)
                                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setContentTitle(
                                        "Awaaz has posted a new article")
                                .setContentText(newMessage)
                                .setContentIntent(mContentIntent)
                                .setSound(soundUri).setVibrate(mVibratePattern);

                        // Pass the Notification to the NotificationManager:
                        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                notificationBuilder.build());

                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Notification Service is working...",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
        }

        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                    log.getAbsolutePath(), log.exists()));

            out.write(new Date(0).toString());
            out.write("\n");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("AppService", "Exception appending to log file", e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's likely that intent.getExtras() is returning null and thus later calling gotBasket.getString throws an NPE. But you really need to post a stack trace to be sure (or use a debugger)

Comment: did you try commenting out the oldId part and seeing if getting oldTime worked?

Comment: I have added LogCat in question @kuujo

Comment: @committedandroider ok i'll try that now

Comment: Now it's giving NPE at `oldTime=gotBasket.getString("KEY3");`

Comment: Show where you're starting the service.

Comment: @ci_ just after `passNotiData.putExtras(basket); `

Comment: Update either your  `CheckService` code or your logcat output. The NPE is reported to have happed on line 70, ... which is a blank line. Any chance you got a `null` `Intent` and your NPE is really on `Bundle gotBasket = intent.getExtras();` ?

Comment: Yes I think that is the reason. I am passing intent to `CheckService` from two classes, one from `AlarmReceiver.java` and other from `NewsFeed.java`. Intent from `Newsfeed.java` contains the bundle. When I remove the startService method from `Alarmreceiver` app doesn't crash. However, if I do that my app wont be able to start on BOOT. Is there any way that I can receive Intent only from `NewsFeed.java`?

Comment: @ci_ at line 70 :  `oldId = gotBasket.getString("KEY1");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `gotBasket` variable is null. Hard to tell from the code snippets, but what does the `intent` variable in CheckService point to? Is it possible that it points to a different instance of CheckService? That would explain why the bundle is missing.